# c# 3rd party application allow on skype

Tags: c#, skype

Did anyone succeed to allow on skype 3rd party applications programatically? How does SEHE do it? Can someone give me a tip?

Comment: Isn't the full source code provided on the SEHE page (http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SEHE) sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

For accessing skype I used this look at this library [skype for net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/skypecontrolapicsharp.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check officical skype developers page - http://developer.skype.com/accessories

and you also can find out great amount of materials on skype developers forum - http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showforum=16&s=9033d4773d46a718989cd74421998e16